# Remove duplicate XML tags with Awk?

Tags: awk, sed

I have a very long custom XML with some issues that I need to fix before I can process in a BASH script.

The custom XML looks like this:

```
<SOME TAGS>
<a:t>The cat</a:t>
<a:t> is</a:t>
<a:t> very</a:t>
<a:t> cute</a:t>
<SOME OTHER TAGS>
<a:t>the </a:t>
<a:t>dog </a:t>
<a:t>is </a:t>
<a:t>also </a:t>
<a:t>very </a:t>
<a:t></a:t>
<a:t>cute and nice</a:t>
<ANOTHER TAG>
```

This is what I am trying to get:

```
<SOME TAGS>
<a:t>The cat is very cute</a:t>
<SOME OTHER TAGS>
<a:t>the dog is also very cute and nice</a:t>
<ANOTHER TAG>
```

- A sentence should start with a <a:t> and ends with a </a:t>
- The sentences are separated by some other tags (I do not have the list of all the possible tags).
- I don't know how many words there are in each sentence.

I tried using a loop with grep on the first <a:t> and then removing the additional tags with sed but it is clearly not going to work.

Is this possible to do this (probably with Awk)?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Sounds like a job for XSLT.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it. If it is possbile, I would still prefer doing this with a Shell script (since this is part of a long Bash script).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your XML is *literally* this regular, it should be easy. The problem with using regular expressions and line-oriented tools on XML is that the XML syntax permits a lot of variations in line breaks and whitespace; but if your input doesn't have that, something like the following should work.

```sh
awk '/^<a:t>/ {
    sub(/^<a:t> */, ""); sub(/ *<\/a:t>/, "");
    sent = (sent ? sent " " : "<a:t>") $0
    next }
sent { print sent "</a:t>"; sent="" }
1
END { if(sent) print sent "</a:t>" }' file.xml
```

We collect the current sentence into the string variable `sent`, then print it out when we see a tag which is different than the sentence tag, or when we reach the end of the input file.

Repeating the print in the END block is unattractive, but I'm too lazy to go back and refactor.

Demo: https://ideone.com/B8SHOG

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`, assuming `<a:t>...</a:t>` are always on their own line and no other text. Since entire input is being slurped, this is not a good solution for very large files.

```sh
$ perl -0777 -pe 's%(^<a:t>.*</a:t>\n)+%$&=~s#(?<!\A)<a:t>|</a:t>\n(?!\z)##rg%gme' ip.txt 
<SOME TAGS>
<a:t>The cat is very cute</a:t>
<SOME OTHER TAGS>
<a:t>the dog is also very cute and nice</a:t>
<ANOTHER TAG>
```

- `-0777` slurp entire input
- `(^<a:t>.*</a:t>\n)+` match one or more lines starting with `<a:t>` and ending with `</a:t>` (`.` won't match newline without `s` flag)

  - `(?<!\A)<a:t>|</a:t>\n(?!\z)` will match `<a:t>` and `</a:t>` except at the start/end of the matched string
- `e` flag allows to use Perl code in the replacement section, used here to perform another substitution
- `m` flag allows `^` to match at start of every line

Comment: Thank you! I will test this solution too. I am running this on some very big files. I am not sure which solution (Perl or Awk) will be faster.

Comment: The Awk solution is probably more robust because it really just reads one file at a time, whereas this Perl solution reads the entire file into memory. It will work but be slow if you have files which are bigger than the available RAM.